# what does 'cmake -E cmake_symlink_libarty' and where is it defined?

Tags: linux, cmake

I am investigating building code for a database connection library named SOCI
and I found

```
... build.make:        cd /build/build_scripts/libs/soci_build/src/core && $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_symlink_library ../../lib/libsoci_core.so.4.0.0 ../../lib/libsoci_core.so.4.0 ../../lib/libsoci_core.so
```

There also lines with

```
$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color ....
```

These commands are not documented and I was not able to 'grep' any trace of their (re)defenition

I could figure out their meaning rougly but I certanly don't like the fact I cannot find them anywhere.

Comment: `cmake` executable has several parameters which are used **only** in code (e.g. Makefile), **generated by CMake** itself. These parameters are purposely not documented: They are not intended for use be anyone else.

Comment: Usually a verbose build should provide you with the info required to diagnose problems. I'd consider undocumented commands like the ones mentioned an implementation detail and not rely on the option having specifig behavour across different cmake versions. Given the name `cmake_symlink_library` probably creates the `...so.4.0` and `....so` symlinks to the actual library file `....so.4.0.0`. `cmake_echo_color` should either set the color used for printing or more likely print a message with a given color. (Some cmake output during the build is green...)

Comment: The problem is that they not only undocumented, they also gives error if you try to execute them in clean setup, without this project. I assumed that there is a way to define custom commands, but I  was not able to find any definitions